# Find global minimum of the function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need to find the global minimum of the function 
$$f ( x) = \langle Ax,x \rangle + 2\langle b ,x\rangle+c$$
where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is constant, $b \in \mathbb {R}^n$, and $A$ is a positive definite matrix.

I know that $f'(x)=(A+A^T)x+2b$ so the minimum should be reached at the solution of the linear equation $$(A+A^T)x=-2b$$
Is there any possible way to know more on it? How the solution should look like?

Comment: $A+A^T$ is a positive, and therefore invertible, matrix. I don't think you can get more explicit than $f(-2(A+A^T)^{-1}b)$ for the minimum.

Comment: Complete the square!

Comment: @ViktorGlombik If we denote $Q=A+A^T$ then $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx+2x^Tb+c=\frac{1}{2}(Qx+2b)^TQ^{-1}(Qx+2b)+c-2b^TQ^{-1}b$ which attains its minimum $c-2b^TQ^{-1}b$ if  $x=-2Q^{-1}b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is positive definite prove that $A = A^T$. Then $x = -A^{-1} (b)$

Comment: I'm not sure that $A$ positive definite implies that it is symmetric.  For the complex adjoint we could prove it, but the problem appears to be stated for the case of real scalars.

Comment: You are right. There are two settings for a positive real matrix defined .

1 ) z * Az > 0 for all complero number z (In this case A is symmetric)

2) x ^ T Ax for every real number x .

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix  In linear algebra, a symmetric n × n real matrix M is said to be positive definite if z^{T}Mz is positive for every non-zero column vector z of n real numbers. Here z^{T} denotes the transpose of z.

Comment: I suspect that the original problem may have defined $A$ to be *symmetric* positive definite.  Some authors use positive definite (of real matrices) in that sense.

Comment: Yes . It's better to think that a positive definite matrix is ​​symmetric by definition, in real case.